# How can I move the icon to the right? Css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Im Trying to create a website using bootstrap.
I want to move the desktop icon a little to the right for better view. I tried floating etc. but I couldn't done it.

I tried floating etc. but I couldn't done it.

[My desire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs3lu.jpg)

```
 <div class="container-fluid mx-auto">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Bootstrap Tutorial</h1>
            <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-10x"></i>
            <p>Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.</p>
          </div>
          <p>This is some text.</p>
          <p>This is another text.</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="jumbotron ">
            <h1>Bootstrap Tutorial2</h1>
            <i class="fa fa-desktop fa-10x "></i>
            <p>Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.</p>
          </div>
          <p>This is some text.</p>
          <p>This is another text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add some of your css codes? A working playground is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your css, `margin-left: auto` should do the trick.

Bootstraps class for this is: `.ml-auto`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the position keyword in CSS: `"position: absolute; left 50px;"`

Gradually increase the number of pixels until the element looks correct.